# Symfony store data in cache issue

Tags: php, symfony

I'm struggling with this, I need to store data in the browser's cache. I'm using Symfony 2.6.1, I use the following code:

```
    if($request->cookies->get('myCookie')){
        /*  do stuff  */

    }else{
        $cookie = new Cookie('myCookie', $myData, 0, '/', null, false, false);            
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);           
        $response->setCache(array(
            'etag'          => 'abcdef',
            'last_modified' => new \DateTime(),
            'max_age'       => 600,
            's_maxage'      => 600,
            // 'private'       => false,
            'public'        => true,
        ));
        $response->send(); 

        /* send a response */
    }
```

I need to 1st check if the cookie "myCookie" exists, if not it should create and store in the browser. My problem is that, when I simply refresh the page to cookie is there, but if I close the browser, when I open again the cookie is not there.

I think that is some configuration/ propriety  in the in the array when I set the cookie **$response->setCache(array(  ... ))**

In the official site, there is not many helpful info about this.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#types-of-caches

Comment: Why don't you just save it within the session? And is it neccessary to save the data after the browser got closed?

Comment: Yes, that data should stay in the cache's browser. When ever the user opens the site, I should be able to read the data stored and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie being gone actually makes sense. You're constructing the cookie with line:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('myCookie', $myData, 0, '/', null, false, false);
```

The third argument (`0`) means that it's a session cookie - will be discarded as soon as you close your browser.

Try something like this:

```
// Cookie stays alive for an hour
$cookie = new Cookie('myCookie', $myData, time() + 3600, '/', null, false, false);
```

Comment: I'hav tried that now, if i use 3600 instead of 0, it won't create a cookie.

Comment: My mistake, sorry about that. The number should not be relative but absolute instead. Try putting `time() + 3600`....